# RabbitMQ Queue Declaration and custom Property Equivalence

Tags: rabbitmq

According to https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#property-equivalence

> When the existing queue attributes are not the same as those in the
>   declaration a channel-level exception with code 406
>   (PRECONDITION_FAILED) will be raised.

This validation works for out of the box arguments like "x-dead-letter-exchange"
BUT
It doesn't work for my custom arguments. My queue just re-declares without error.

Is it proper behavior? 
Can I add my custom argument to Equivalence validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ only verifies the set of well-known x-* declare arguments -

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.7.11/src/rabbit_amqqueue.erl#L578-L588

as well as a couple other queue attributes -

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.7.11/src/rabbit_amqqueue.erl#L533-L534